# JSON Store can't load PHP data - EXTJS 4

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4, store

```
Ext.define('GoogleMarkerModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
        {name: 'ID',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'Locating',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'MainPower',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'Acc',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'PowerOff',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'Alarm',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'Speed',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'Direction',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'Latitude',    type: 'float'},
        {name: 'Longitude',    type: 'float'},
        {name: 'DateTime',    type: 'date'},
        {name: 'MainID',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'IOState',    type: 'int'},
        {name: 'OilState',    type: 'int'}]
    });

    var MarkerStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        model: 'GoogleMarkerModel',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'get-googlemarker.php',
            baseParams: {  //here you can define params you want to be sent on each request from this store
                        mainid: 'value1'
                        },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                idProperty:'MainID',
            }

        }
    });
```

this code i use to call the MarkerStore and passing the parameter mainid with value 1

```
MarkerStore.load({
                        params: {  //here you can define params on 'per request' basis
                                mainid: 1,
                                }
                        })
```

when i use web browser to get-googlemarker.php and mainid=1 will return those value

```
http://localhost/GPS/examples/tabs/get-googlemarker.php?mainid=1

[{"ID":"1808","Locating":"1","MainPower":"0","Acc":"1","PowerOff":"1","Alarm":"128","Speed":"0","Direction":"293","Latitude":"5.391788482666016","Longitude":"100.29693603515625","DateTime":"2013-02-19 15:44:36","MainID":"1","IOState":"0","OilState":"0"}]
```

but i m trying to list out all data,unfortunately the JSON store are null, i suspect the data are not store in the MarkerStore, below code are i m trying to list out the data,but is nothing write on console FireBug.

```
MarkerStore.each( function (model) {
    console.log( model.get('MainID') ); 
    });
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MarkerStore.on('load', function(store, records) {
    for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    console.log(records[i].get('Latitude'));
    lati = records[i].get('Latitude'); 
    };
});
```

should use this code, then will print the data on console. the above question print store data code are wrong,actually data are success saved in JSON store

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `autoload = true` property from the store.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, but the main problem is when you call MarkerStore.each the store is empty at this time(Ajax is Asynchronous). Your script is faster as the ajax with the data. If you use the following simple snippet you will see your "mainID".

```
setTimeout(function(){
        MarkerStore.each( function (model) {
                console.log( model.get('MainID') );
        });     
    }, 1500, MarkerStore);
```